# cprofile compile error on python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cprofile

using cProfile of python, I cprofiled my code, but I keep getting this error related with compile() and null character which I can't quite understand.

The error message is:

> [cProfileV]: cProfile output available at http://127.0.0.1:4000
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/cprofilev", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('CProfileV==1.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'cprofilev')()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cprofilev.py", line 217, in main
>       code = compile(fp.read(), progname, 'exec')
>   TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes

Is it a problem with my client code, or the server just isn't up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the error is caused by a mismatch between versions of cprofile and cprofilev.

Cprofilev can be run directly using:

`python -m cprofilev your_script.py`

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked [before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397903/typeerror-compile-expected-string-without-null-bytes)

Anyhow, the error means you're recieving a string which you cannot read well, because it includes nulls. That means the server is up & responding but you cannot read the respond properly. That is because it's in another format, which is very likely JSON. try using the JSON module, included in python 2.6 and beyond; you could see some examples for it, [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) If you'll provide us with your code, I can help you convert your application into a JSON-friendly one. :)